# Excluding Classes using Maven Shade Plugin not working

Tags: java, maven

The classes added to exclude in maven shade plugin don't get excluded.

My pom.xml has one dependency which has shaded classes conflicting with other dependencies.

So I added the path to those classes in maven shade plugin to exclude them.

I have this for maven shade plugin.

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <executions>

                <execution>

                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                            <filter>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>io.confluent.shaded.kafka.serializers.subject.*</exclude>
              <exclude>io/confluent/shaded/kafka/serializers/subject/*</exclude>

                            </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <mainClass>com.expediagroup.das.businessevent.CommerceBusinessBookingEventMetricCalculatorApp</mainClass>
                            <layout>JAR</layout>
                        </configuration>

                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After compiling it still shows those classes not being removed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#filters - the example in documentation uses ant patterns, not class names.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov That has not worked as well for me

Comment: If you have spring boot application don't use maven-shade-plugin use spring-boot-maven-plugin instead....

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried using filter conditions first in spring-boot-maven-plugin, but didn't work. So migrated to maven shade plugin. I'll go back to it.

Comment: `My pom.xml has one dependency which has shaded classes conflicting with other dependencies` That sounds like the dependency is the culprit... Are those deps not provided by other deps instead of the shaded one???

Comment: "After compiling it still shows those classes not being removed." (a) who is "it" showing classes not being removed?  (b) "not being removed" from where? the point here - shade plugin removes filtered files from uber-jar, but don't touch anythin in target/classes directory

Comment: @ursa Running the application gives an error when the application picks the shaded classes at runtime instead of the io.confluent classes.